# Order of function execution in Haskell

Tags: haskell, recursion, search, tree

I have a data object for trees like this:

```hs
data Tree = Empty | Node Int [Tree] deriving (Show, Eq)
```

Here is my searching function:

```hs
searchValueTree :: Tree -> Int -> Bool
searchValueTree Empty _ = False
searchValueTree (Node a list) valueSearch
 | a == valueSearch = True
 | otherwise = helperTree list valueSearch

--help function
helperTree :: [Tree] -> Int -> Bool
helperTree [] _ = False
helperTree (x:xs) value = searchValueTree x value || helperTree xs value
```

```hs
test::Bool
test = searchValueTree (Node 5 [Node 4 [Node 3 [Empty]], Node 7 [Empty], Leer]) 3
```

The question is, when I'm in the helper function and I call `searchValueTree x value` and I haven't found my value, which is called first: `helperTree list valueSearch` in `searchValueTree`, or  `helperTree xs value` in `helperTree`?
I can't figure out the order of execution.

Comment: The order of execution in Haskell is extremely strange and much weirder than you expect, but the short answer is that it generally doesn't matter.  (It's also not clear which parts of the code you're trying to refer to in which part is called next -- helperTree is called and then it's evaluated on the list.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It goes something like this:

```
searchValueTree x value || helperTree xs value
-> {- definition of || -}
case searchValueTree x value of
    True -> True
    False -> helperTree xs value
-> {- pattern match forces evaluation of the call to searchValueTree -}
case (case x of
    Empty -> False
    Node a list | a == value -> True
                | otherwise -> helperTree list value
    ) of
    True -> True
    False -> helperTree xs value
-> {- assuming x matches Node a list and a /= value -}
case let Node _ list = x in helperTree list value of
    True -> True
    False -> helperTree xs value
```

I believe in your parlance this means that `helperTree list valueSearch` is called in `searchValueTree` before `helperTree xs value` is called in `helperTree`. From here, because the first argument to `(||)` has not yet reached a form that lets the pattern match choose between its branches, evaluation continues in the scrutinee of the case, namely in `let Node _ list = x in helperTree list value`.